# How can I change between videos faster?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flvplayback

I'm using the FLVPlayback component from Flash CS5 to make a videoplayer that uses an XML file as a plyalist, but I need them to play one after the other faster, at this moment it takess 1 sec or a little more to chaange to the next one.

Here is my as3 code:

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,LoadData);

var playlist:XML = new XML();
var amountOfVideos:Number=0;
var currentVideo:Number=0;

vid.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, PlayNextVideo);

   function LoadData(e:Event){
    playlist=XML(e.target.data);
    amountOfVideos=playlist.video.length();
    ChangeVideo();
   }

   function PlayNextVideo(e:Event){
    currentVideo++;
    if (currentVideo < amountOfVideos){
        ChangeVideo();
    }
   }
   function ChangeVideo():void{
    vid.source=playlist.video.@src[currentVideo];   
   }

   loader.load(new URLRequest('video-list.xml'));
```

I know that there are some flash players that I can use, but it need to be made by me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually make it faster, because the 1 second you're talking about is used for loading the video.

One thing, which is not the best solution, but will help as a workaround is to have 2 `FLVPlayback` controls on the stage, 1 playing, 1 not visible and stopped. You'll check if the first video is getting close to its end and if so you start second video 1-2 seconds earlier and switch their visibilities.

Comment: Well this seems to be a good option, but it only works if I use it local, once I upload the proyect to my host I get some problems, i guess its because of the buffering time. I guess now my best option is to merge multiple FLV files, but I just don't know how.

Comment: You can use Adobe After Effects for that. There might also be some third party software for that. Or you can embed the videos into the SWF and you won't have to stream or buffer it, although loading time of the SWF will increase.